# Can I calibrate this thermostat? (Cadet brand, 240V)

Tags: heating, thermostat

My thermostat operates but seems to be badly calibrated. It will hold temperature, and you can adjust that temperature, but its not the temperature it says on the dial! It goes much higher than the stated number.

For example: to get the room to 70 F, you have to set it to about 55. To keep the nighttime temp. colder around 55, you have to turn it to around 40-45 but not as far as "off". As you turn it there are some audible clicks of either the mechanism or relay as it switches on/off (I think that's what I'm hearing).

It is a 240V line-voltage thermostat that controls an electric baseboard heater.

Under the cover there are two screws (allen key I think) which I imagine might be used to calibrate the mechanism. I asked the manufacturer and they said they don't have any manuals for this 20-30 year old model.

I could just experiment but thought it was better to ask here first rather than risk making it worse... but I'll do that if I can't find any other information.

---

The top photo was taken when I set it back from 70 (which it overshot) to a nighttime temp.

[image]

[image]

Comment: "for this 20-30 year old model". Yeah, I think it is time to put this one to rest and buy a new one.

Comment: @Gunner which I'll do if I need to. But since it has (apparent) adjustments that seemed worth trying first.

Comment: I'd experiment with it. Many  questions and problems on this site are  about new thermostats that don't work at all.

Comment: @JACK that's probably a good idea, but I was hoping at least for a theory of what the two screws do before I just randomly start making changes. In part this is because its going to be a long process to test it since I'll have to wait for the room temp to rise/fall.

Comment: I wish I could help you with that.  Can you disassemble it further to see what  those  screws  adjust?  Caution, it's a line voltage thermostat so disconnect power before doing anything.

Comment: @JACK I think that's a good suggestion once I've got no other options - ie if I'm otherwise going to replace it anyway, nothing to lose! I appreciate your input & caution about the 240V.

Comment: That flap where the two screws are... it looks like it's on a hinge at the top... does it lift up?

Comment: There appears to be third screw (Phillips or combo slotted) in the middle with some writing and an arrow, but I can't make out the writing.

Comment: @JACK it does look like a hinge but in fact its just printing on the metal, its a single solid piece. Sorry that was not clearly visible in the photo.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I can't either (even on the original photo) - I'll take a closer look / better photo if I can.

Comment: Many times there were screws with red paint on the calibration screws , I would try not a large change maybe 1 turn and see if that makes a difference. One may be for span the range between turn on and off and the other that brings the scale closer to actual . So prior to adjusting note the temp the system turns on at and off at for a given dial setting, then make an adjustment and see what the change is.

Comment: The knob turns a threaded spindle that changes the preload applied to the bimetallic element - which is usually a dark blueish color with printing on it just like that plate, though they're not usually formed into shapes apart from the slight dishing that causes them to flip from one curvature to the other at the set point.  Anyway, have you pulled the knob off? It might be just a matter of repositioning the knob.